# Why is the hover background changing to white?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/EZbmw/

The button has a style blue background and the `:hover` state should maintain that blue background. In the CSS, you'll see I removed the background from `.blue:hover` and that made the background disappear altogether.

Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the `.button` styling. Your `.button:hover` includes a `background: #eee`.

You would need to continue overriding the `:hover` styling within your `.button`.